# Python looping to wrong point

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

In python 3.3 I am making a game with two while trues in it when I run it it loops to the first while true rather than the second. why does it do this?
  first part of my code as follows:

```
while True:
   # Callum Dashfield
   print ("You must answer all questions in block capitals")
   print ("Welcome to maze runner")
   print ("To learn about the controls press C")
   print ("To learn the about the different types T")
   print ("To play press START")
   run = input ()
   #Controls
   if run == "C":
      print ("To attack press H")
      print ("To walk forward press W")
      print ("To turn left press A")
      print ("To turn right press D")
      print ("To turn around press S")
      print ("To block press B")
      print ("To see what you are carrying press E")
      print ("To open stats press Q")
      print ("To open this screen press C")
      print ("To go back to the main menu press M")
      return_to_menu = input()
      if return_to_menu != "M":
         break
```

this is the second loop:

```
while True:
   solider_close = ['7', '8' , '9', '10']
   from random import choice
   solider_long = ['1', '2', '3']
   from random import choice
   solider_speed = [ '4', '5', '6']
   from random import choice 
   solider_block = [ '4', '5', '6']            
   print ("You choose solider")
   print ("Your stats: close combat - " + choice(solider_close))
   print ("            long range combat - " + choice(solider_long))
   print ("            long range combat - " + choice(solider_speed))
   print ("            long range combat - " + choice(solider_block))
   print ("Press S to continue")
   continues = input ()
   if continues == "Y":
   #RESET  
   else:
      break
```

Comment: and where is the second loop?

Comment: there is one at the begining of the program but I can not post all the code because there is to much for it to aaccept it

Comment: Then eliminate the parts that don't matter. For example, your redundant imports and the prints could be omitted above.

Comment: You should remove everything that does not matter: your prints, variables that are not used for loops control, then the whole code should be postable here. Once it is done - provide as with exact behavior and expected one, in order to receive any help, as for now it is far from being clear what is really the problem